# postgres lo_unlink not deleting objects

Tags: postgresql

Im little bit new in postgres, but I have problem related with disk space. now I have 2GB free space, I need to delete some of largeobjects. Situation is like this:
I have table espbidocuments that stores OID with ID to pg_largeobject table where is stored my files. pg_largeobject now is 87,201,636,352 bytes size and I need to shrink. I tried deleting references from espbidocuments, so LO will be orphans, then I ran function lo_unlink(oid) and get result 1, so I think that my files are deleted, but still when I selecting from pg_largeobject table, I get that they exist in that table and pg_largeobject table size is not lesser, size is the same. I cant do vacuum because tables size is 80+GB and free space is ~2GB... how remove those darn largeobject?

Comment: This is not a programming question so it is off-topic on stackoverflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , [MCVE] and [Ask] for further informations.

Comment: But alot of questions about this are in stackoverflow. So I asked it. I did not found answer in other questions, why my largeobejcts is not deleting from database, what commands should I use.

Comment: Please come up with a reproducible test case that illustrates your claim. SQL, not words, will make the case clear.